# Multidimensional Array zip array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have two array like:

```
val one = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
val two = Array(4, 5, 6, 7)
var three = one zip two map{case(a, b) => a * b}
```

It's ok.

But I have a multidimensional Array and a one-dimensional array now, like this:

```
val mulOne = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4),Array(5, 6, 7, 8),Array(9, 10, 11, 12))
val one_arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I would like to multiplication them, how can I do this in scala?

Comment: What do you want your output to be?

Comment: 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 +4*4

5*1 + 6*2 + 7*3 + 8*4

.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
val tmpArr = mulOne.map(_ zip one_arr).map(_.map{case(a,b) => a*b})
```

This would give you `Array(Array(1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4), Array(5*1, 6*2, 7*3, 8*4), Array(9*1, 10*2, 11*3, 12*4))`.

Here `mulOne.map(_ zip one_arr)` maps each internal array of `mulOne` with corresponding element of `one_arr` to create pairs like: `Array(Array((1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)), ..)` (*Note*: I have used placeholder syntax). In the next step `.map(_.map{case(a,b) => a*b})` multiplies each elements of pair to give
output like: `Array(Array(1, 4, 9, 16),..)`

Then you could use:

```
tmpArr.map(_.reduce(_ + _))
```

to get sum of all internal `Array`s to get `Array(30, 70, 110)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
mulOne.map{x => (x, one_arr)}.map { case(one, two) => one zip two map{case(a, b) => a * b} }
```

`mulOne.map{x => (x, one_arr)}` => for every array inside `mulOne`, create a tuple with content of one_arr.

`.map { case(one, two) => one zip two map{case(a, b) => a * b} }` is basically the operation that you performed in your first example on every tuple that were created in the first step.

Comment: It's helpful for me, too.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using a for comprehension like this,

```
val prods = 
  for { xs <- mulOne
       zx = one_arr zip xs
       (a,b) <- zx
      } yield a*b
```

and so

```
prods.sum
```

delivers the final result.